# Ionic 2 File native how to write and read simple and pdf file

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i want to read and write file using ionic 2 native File.i have search on documentation.but i want to create a pdf file store it into mobile then open it..how can i do this.?

like following question.

[How to store pdf file on Local Storage Root Directory in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44264105/how-to-store-pdf-file-on-local-storage-root-directory-in-ionic-2)